# Magento 2, new admin page redirects to admin index page

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, grid

I need to make  new admin page with a grid, in M2, and along with it, a menu link that will link to it. I have made a menu item successfully, and it looks like it is linked to correct URL, but when I click on it, I am just redirected to admin index page. What am I missing here?
My `Namespace/Modulename/etc/acl.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
     <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Namespace_Modulename::griglia" title="Modulename Griglia" sortOrder="51">
                    <resource id="Namespace_Modulename::griglia_child_resource" title="Grigla Child Resource" sortOrder="10"/>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

My `etc/adminhtml/menu.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Namespace_Modulename::index" title="Modulename" module="Namespace_Modulename" sortOrder="51" resource="Namespace_Modulename::index"/>
        <add id="Namespace_Modulename::griglia" title="Griglia" module="Namespace_Modulename" sortOrder="10" action="modulename/griglia" resource="Namespace_Modulename::griglia" parent="Namespace_Modulename::index"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

My `etc/adminhtml/routes.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin"> <!-- This part is different from frontend -->
        <route id="modulename" frontName="modulename">
            <module name="Namespace_Modulename" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Comment: have u add `routes.xml`?

Comment: you should also add here your routes xml and menu xml at least. Maybe list your controllers as well

Comment: Ok, I didn't add routes.xml. Will do and update the question. menu.xml is added.

Comment: Ok added, and still I am not getting the page. I added acl.xml and template, and routes.xml, and layout for the page.

Comment: do you check request get in controller?

Comment: I got the out put, by putting "HARDCODED TEXT" in execute and return; I want to have my custom template however.

Comment: There is a form? Can you post your controller?

Comment: I will make another question, this one is resolved, the link is now routed correctly, and URL displayed correctly in browser.

Answer (score 0):

I got the out put, by putting "HARDCODED TEXT" in execute and return; . I want to have my custom template however. Will post in another question.